# Erro de conversão na cláusula where ao filtrar registros usando o EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, expressões-lambda

Estou obtendo uma lista de registros e filtrando de acordo com o parâmetro informado. O problema é que está aparecendo um erro no qual desconheço (conforme imagem). Há duas classes : PessoaDocumento e DocumentoTipo... Sendo que, ao obter uma lista de documentos, deve-se trazer os tipos de documentos relacionados.

O que está errado?

```
public IQueryable<PessoaDocumento> GetPaginated(string filter, int initialPage, int pageSize, out int totalRecords, out int recordsFiltered, int pessoaId, bool @readonly = false)
{
    var data = DbSet
       .Include(x => x.DocumentoTipo)
       .Where(x => x.PessoaId == pessoaId)
       .AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();

    totalRecords = data.Count();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    {
        data = data.Where(x =>
         !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.NumeroDocumento) ? x.NumeroDocumento.Contains(filter.ToUpper()) : false
         || x.DocumentoTipo != null ? x.DocumentoTipo.Descricao.Contains(filter.ToUpper()) : false
         || x.DocumentoTipo != null ? x.DocumentoTipo.Sigla.Contains(filter.ToUpper()) : false
        );
    }

    recordsFiltered = data.Count();

    if (recordsFiltered == 0)
        totalRecords = 0;

    data = data
        .Skip(initialPage)
        .Take(pageSize);

    return data;
}


public class PessoaDocumento : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DocumentoTipoId { get; set; }

    private string numeroDocumento;
    public string NumeroDocumento
    {
        get { return numeroDocumento; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                numeroDocumento = value.Trim().ToUpper();
            }
        }
    }   
    
     public virtual DocumentoTipo DocumentoTipo { get; private set; }
}



public class DocumentoTipo : Entity
{
    private string codigoControle;
    public string CodigoControle
    {
        get { return codigoControle; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                codigoControle = value.ToUpper().Trim();
            else
                codigoControle = value;
        }
    }

    private string descricao;
    public string Descricao
    {
        get { return descricao; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                descricao = value.ToUpper().Trim();
            else
                descricao = value;
        }
    }

    private string sigla;
    public string Sigla
    {
        get { return sigla; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                sigla = value.ToUpper().Trim();
            else
                sigla = value;
        }
    }
    
    public virtual ICollection<PessoaDocumento> PessoasDocumentos { get; private set; }
}


public abstract class Entity
{
    //public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public int Id { get; protected set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var compareTo = obj as Entity;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, compareTo)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, compareTo)) return false;

        return Id.Equals(compareTo.Id);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Entity a, Entity b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) && ReferenceEquals(b, null))
            return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) || ReferenceEquals(b, null))
            return false;

        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Entity a, Entity b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (GetType().GetHashCode() * 907) + Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GetType().Name + " [Id=" + Id + "]";
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `data = data.Where(..` acho que deveria criar outro objeto, não atribuir ao próprio data. Pra além disso, acho que deveria retornar uma lista ai, acho que falta no final um `.ToList();`

Comment: Olá @Ricardo Pontual! Mesmo seguindo suas dicas, o erro persiste! Isso parece ser algum problema do EF Core 2.0. :(

Comment: Pela msg de erro, parece um problema de conversão entre os campos Id das classes, pois são herdados da classe Entity...